# Relational Databases in Yii

Tags: php, yii, gii, yii-cactiverecord

So I've tried this: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/285/accessing-data-in-a-join-table-with-the-related-models

Basically I have a table called User which relates to ToolAccess; related via a primary key on User and a field for userID on ToolAccess. Now tool access relates to the table Tool which contains a ToolID. Now this doesn't work in Yii, I can't seem to get the toolName  field off of the tool table using Yii. Any ideas on how to do this on a Active Record?

I'm using giix if that matters.

Relations code:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'usergalleries' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Usergallery', 'userid'),
        'userinroles' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Userinroles', 'userid'),
        'userfailedlogin' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Userfailedlogin','userid'),
        // table name, relation, class name, relation key
        'toolaccess' =>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Toolaccess','userid'),
        'tool' =>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Tool','toolid')
    );
}
```

Comment: But what's the problem you are having?

Comment: I don't know how I can get the value from the tool name column

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand at first. And how are toolaccess and tool related? By toolid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your schema looks something like this:

```
User table             tool_access table          Tool table

id | other columns     userid | toolid            id | name | other columns
```

In this case, the `User` model should have a relation like this (note that the tools will be ordered by name in this case):

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        // other relations here...
        'tools' =>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Tool', 'tool_access(userid,toolid)',
          'order' => 'tools.name',
        ),
    );
}
```

and the code to read the tools should look like this:

```
$user = User::model()->with('tools')->findByPk($id);
foreach($user->tools as $tool) {
    echo $tool->name;
}
```

I used eager loading of the `tools` here mostly because of personal preference, using lazy loading should work just as well in this case. But eager loading should be preferred whenever you're processing multiple `User` records at once.

Comment: @Snow_Mac: I learned mostly from these links: The definitive guide to Yii: [Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar) - [Relational Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr), trial and error, and stepping through the code with xdebug (though that shouldn't be necessary for beginners). The `gii` code generator tool can generate the Active Record classes for you, and if your database schema includes foreign keys (it *really* should, for data integrity reasons), it can use those to infer these relations automatically.

Answer (score 0):

So if I have understood it properly, user and tool are related in a many-to-many relationship by their primary keys.

So you should define this relationship in the User model like:

```
'tools' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Tool', 'tool_access(userid, toolid)', 'index' => 'id'),
```

This way you can access the name of the tool after getting the user model

```
$user = User::model->findByPk($id);
$tools = $user->tools;
foreach ($tools as $tool)
{
    echo $tool->name;
}
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: User and tool access are related via the field USERID. Tool and user are not related, but tool and tool access are related.

Comment: Can you post your database schema?